# Bootstrap form controls alignment when resizing window

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3.3 and angular here.

I am trying to create a search filter above my grid but having some alignment issues. In full page I can see them aligned correctly, but when I try to resize the page all my form controls get jumbled up and down. I believe these is some css class which is missing but cant seem to figure out what is that. Could anyone point me in right direction.

I also created a stackblitz demo here at:
https://angular-datrange-enhq8w.stackblitz.io/

If you resize the window you would see what I am talking about.

Here is the stackblitz editor for this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datrange-enhq8w

Below is some relevant code:

```
<div id="filters"> 
  <form [formGroup]="filtersForm"  >
    <div class="row padding-top-10">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-group" style="margin-right:65px">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" style="height:33px" autocomplete="off" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" />
      </div>
    </div>
   </form> 
 </div>
```

Also on side note if you see the demo somehow I feel my dropdown does has the right style, is there some extra bootstrap 3 style I can add for this.

Thanks for looking into.

Anyone for inputs?

Comment: Try to add "form-control" class to input elements

Comment: @claudiu.nicola nope, did not work.

Comment: you are killing the grid with your "style="margin-right:65px". Your options are to addapt your margin to the screensizes or use a flex-layout your own. PS: This happens because your content-width is larger then the container-width

Comment: You have issues for medium sized devices. Give it 2 cols : col-md-2

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't be styling your grid. Style the grid contents.

Comment: @MullisS sorry I am not very comfortable with CSS so tried to adjust with style. If I remove the style tag both the controls get fixed with each other with no spacing.  Dont want to get spoon fed but can you provide what exactly you mean by giving above, I mean giving 2 cols etc.

Answer (score 0):

The grid system for bootstrap states that every row must be wrapped by a container class.

```html
<div id="filters">
        <form [formGroup]="filtersForm">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row padding-top-10">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-group" style="margin-right:65px">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" style="height:33px" autocomplete="off"
                            class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This does not solve the issue of changing the size. The bootstrap grid system is setup like this: For every row, there are 12 columns. What you are saying is that for the div with the class col-xs-12, make the element in that class have a width of 100% when the screen size is extra small. You are also saying that when it hits the col-md-1 (medium screen size breakpoint), it should have a width of 8.3333%. You have 6 divs in that page you provided. Since you have 6 divs, 12 columns / 6 divs = 2 columns per div. Therefore your code should be refactored to something like this:

```html
<div id="filters">
        <form [formGroup]="filtersForm">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row padding-top-10">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 form-group" style="margin-right:65px">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" style="height:33px" autocomplete="off"
                            class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Notice how I removed col-sm-12.. this is because col-xs-12 will set the width for every screen size up to the next given class. In this case you have col-xs-12, therefore when the screen size is xs and sm, it'll have a width of 100%. When it hits the md breakpoint, it'll change the width to 2/12 and have the same width for lg and xl screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have made the changes as you suggested here: Demo: https://angular-datrange-enhq8w.stackblitz.io Editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datrange-enhq8w . Now with your code this makes my filters align vertically one after another. I want all controls in one horizontal row.

Answer (score 0):

Check out bootstrap [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/).
The base syntax is:

- container | container-fluid

  - row

    - columns (the total of `col` must be 12)

Also, there is no need of aditional margins on your `col` divs.

```
<div id="filters"> 
  <form class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row padding-top-10">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="age">Age Range</label>
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="age">
            <option [selected] value="">All</option>
            <option *ngFor="let age of ages" value='{{age}}'>
              {{age}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

If you want to persist all columns in a single row even on small screens, remove `col-xs-12` and change `col-md-2` to `col-xs-2`.

Comment: I tried to fit and updated with your suggestions but this does not works as expected. I have about 6-7 controls.  See my updated demo: https://angular-datrange-enhq8w.stackblitz.io/ . Here is the editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datrange-enhq8w

Comment: Edit your `<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-2">` to `<div class="col-2">` and remove all margins from these divs. Also, you must add "form-control" class to all of your input fields.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested here: https://angular-datrange-enhq8w.stackblitz.io/  and it works to some extent : https://angular-datrange-enhq8w.stackblitz.io/ But if you try to resize the window, after one point the form controls get jumbled. What I am looking for is after at certain width if the size of the window is small, the form controls should lay out vertically.